# How to programmatically get the chrome extension ID

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to open/interact with the chrome extension from the webpage in my local(Not installed the chrome extension from the web store). For that, i have this piece of code

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, {}, function(){ // code })
```

Here **extensionId** is the ID which i manually copied from the chrome extension. And it is working.

Is there any way to get the chrome extension ID programmatically in the webpage? Or is there any other way to open/interact with the chrome extension programmatically?

Comment: No, but the extension can expose itself to the page via a standard DOM CustomEvent, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to the chrome ext, where i have to add the code. What i did is, added `On the receiving side` code added in background.js and `On the initiator side` code added in the webpage. This case it is not working. Did i miss any thing?

Comment: As the answer says the communication is between the *content script* and the page script.

Comment: I just updated the question with your code, still chrome ext is not opening. Let me know if i miss any thing.

Comment: Content scripts can't use chrome.windows API.

Comment: Yeah, so i just wanted to open a chrome ext from the web page. So you think i have to use the chrome ext id for that? is that only way?

Comment: The content script can send a [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to its background script, which will create the window.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little old, but [this answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376396/8581173) answers you directly.
You may use `chrome.runtime.id` to fetch this value. Cheers